# One of the else if statements doesn't perform even if the condition verifies

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Whenever I write a name with over 6 letters it still prints

> that isn't a very long name

instead of

> that's such a long name

I know this must be a basic question and that it might be pretty straightforward, but I just can't get it to work. I would appreciate any ideas on why it doesn't perform as it's supposed to.

```
let myName = prompt('What is your name?');

if (myName.length <= 3) {
  document.write('That is such a short name!');
}
else if (3 < myName.length < 6) {
  document.write('That isn\'t a very long name');
}
else if (myName.length >= 6) {
  document.write('That\'s such a long name!');
} 
else {
  document.write('Nop');
}
```

Comment: This is javascript! So: `3 < myName.length // true` then, `true < 6 //true`. What you want is `3 < myName.length && myName.length < 6`

Comment: What @CRice says.  `3 < myName.length < 6` won't work in any curly-brace language, including Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

One of your expressions isn't doing what you think it does.

```
else if (3 < myName.length < 6) {
```

Both `3 < myName.length` and `myName.length < 6` evaluate to true, so they'll almost always be hit.

To check for multiple conditions you need an "and" operator, which is `&&` in Javascript

```
else if (myName.length > 3 && myName.length < 6) {
```

Notice how we've also flipped the expression so that `myName.length` is always first. This makes it easier to read aloud

> if myName.length is greater than 3 and myName.length is less than 6...

Comment: CRice's comment below the question explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that -- because you're using 'else' statements -- about half of your conditions are redundant.

Your first condition, for example, checks if the size of the string is less than or equal to 3; this is ok.

Your second condition, however, will only be tested if the length is greater than 3, so you don't have to check it again.

Here is a simplified version of your logic:

```
let myName = prompt('What is your name?');

if (myName.length <= 3) {
  document.write('That is such a short name!');
}

else if (myName.length < 6) {
  document.write('That isn\'t a very long name');
}

else {
  document.write('That\'s such a long name!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I actually made it like this for the sake of testing. For instance, I added another else if and used the string « nop »  which I didn’t have before, becayse my code wasn’t working properly so I tried changing it as you can see.